# How to get rid of decimal points in dataframe that is NOT numbers

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I just want to get rid of characters (or whatever you want to call it)that has ".xxxxx"

| Gene_ID |
| --- |
| ENSG00000000003.14 |
| ENSG00000000005.5 |
| ERCC-00164 |
| ENSG00000002586.18_PAR_Y |
| ENSG00000054803.3 |
| ERCC-00012 |
| ENSG00000284332.1 |

So this is how I want it to look like:

| Gene_ID |
| --- |
| ENSG00000000003 |
| ENSG00000000005 |
| ERCC-00164 |
| ENSG00000002586 |
| ENSG00000054803 |
| ERCC-00012 |
| ENSG00000284332 |

This is what I have tried:

```
df['Gene_ID'].str.replace('.',''))
```

but when I do that it only gets rid of the decimal not the characters that comes after the decimal point.

Note: the actual column is much longer than what I am showing on stack which has all that ".xxxx"

Comment: you need to do `df['Gene_ID'].str.replace('[.].*','', regex = True))` You have to use regex whereby `.` is a metacharacter and therefore has to be placed in a character class or even escaped.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Series.str.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) with regex `(\..*)$` for decimal and any value, `$` is for end of string:

```
df['Gene_ID'] = df['Gene_ID'].str.replace('(\..*)$','', regex=True)
print (df)
           Gene_ID
0  ENSG00000000003
1  ENSG00000000005
2       ERCC-00164
3  ENSG00000002586
4  ENSG00000054803
5       ERCC-00012
6  ENSG00000284332
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the comment above:

Note that `.` is a metacharacter which represents Anything apart from the line breaks, hence to match a literal `.` you need to  escape it by a backslash or put in a character class ie inside brackets.

```
df['Gene_ID'] = df['Gene_ID'].str.replace('[.].*','', regex = True)

df
           Gene_ID
0  ENSG00000000003
1  ENSG00000000005
2       ERCC-00164
3  ENSG00000002586
4  ENSG00000054803
5       ERCC-00012
6  ENSG00000284332
```